# How to acces Vue computed properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to use computed property in another one or inside method and get the error:
`Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Vue'`

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
  computed: {
    comments(): Comment[] {
      return this.$store.getters['comments/getComments'];
    },
    hasComments(): boolean {
      return (0 !== this.comments.length); // Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Vue'
    }
  }
})
export default class Test extends Vue {
  public get commentsCount(): number {
    return this.comments.length; // Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Vue'
  }
}
```

I replace it with `(this as any).comments` and it works without errors, but what's the point to use `typescript` and ignore type checks with `any`.

Comment: Consider using [`vuex-class`](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class) to use the Vuex store from TypeScript. It would simplify your code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `comments` exists in the **Javascript** runtime, the problem here is that it is not defined in **Typescript**, you can simply fix this by declaring the variable and then using the `!` operator after the definition of your variable, which is the `non-null` assertion operation, it tells to Typescript that your variable is being initialized somewhere else (in this case by the *decorator*)

**Snippet**:

```
  public comments!: TYPE_OF_COMMENTS;
```

**Full code**:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
  computed: {
    comments(): Comment[] {
      return this.$store.getters['comments/getComments'];
    },
    hasComments(this: Test): boolean {
      return (0 !== this.comments.length);
    }
  }
})
export default class Test extends Vue {
  public comments!: TYPE_OF_COMMENTS;

  public get commentsCount(): number {
    return this.comments.length; // Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Vue'
  }
}
```

**Update:**

For the case of `hasComments` you can change the provided value for the `this` instance as you can point to your actual component instead of the default `Vue` instance.

You can achieve it like this:

```
    hasComments(this: Test): boolean { 
      return (0 !== this.comments.length);
    }
```

As you can see the `this` instance has the type definitions of the component (Test).

Comment: It helps with `get commentsCount()`, but it still generating same error in `hasComments()`:
`Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar errors in the past in Vue 2 (Vue 3 is much better especially with the composition api). There was never a single specific fix but one common fix was to make sure my computed properties had an accurate return type and that there was a default value utilized for my computed property.

I would've added this as a comment but I don't have enough rep but can you try providing a default value in your comments() return. You've typed it to return a Comment[] but Typescript/Vue might not know that the store value you're fetching is exactly that (or if it even exists yet).